# I'm getting {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client clientId does not exist."} while obtaing access token in karate API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, karate

I'm getting {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client clientId does not exist."} while obtaing access  token in karate API framework and status code was 400

Script I used

```
Feature: Get Token

Background:
* header Content-Type = 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
* header X-Amz-Target = 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth'


  Scenario: GEt access token
    Given url 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
    And request {"AuthParameters" : {"REFRESH_TOKEN" : refreshToken},"AuthFlow" : "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH","ClientId" : clientId } 
    When method post 
    Then status 200
    * print response
```

here I'm passing refresh token and client Id from karate-config.js file.

```
I'm getting {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client clientId does not exist."} while obtaing access  token in karate API framework and status code was 400

Script I used
```

Feature: Get Token

Background:

- header Content-Type = 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
- header X-Amz-Target = 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth'

  Scenario: GEt access token
  Given url 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
  And request {"AuthParameters" : {"REFRESH_TOKEN" : refreshToken},"AuthFlow" : "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH","ClientId" : clientId }
  When method post
  Then status 200

  - print response

```
here I'm passing refresh token and client Id from karate-config.js file.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is this change:

```
And request {"AuthParameters" : {"REFRESH_TOKEN" : '#(refreshToken)' },"AuthFlow" : "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH","ClientId" : '#(clientId)' }
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#embedded-expressions

Otherwise no one can help you if your request data is wrong.